# How to go over file content?

Tags: r, file

Is there a way to explore a file content using R standard package? I would like to provide a path to a folder and obtain it's content just for this directory and if I would like to - also contents of those inside files.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "explore a file content", but `list.files(..)` will list the files in a directory (options include `pattern=` and `recursive=` for finding various levels/types of files), and `readLines(..)` will read the contents of a text file into a `character` vector (each element is a newline-delimited line).

Comment: If you wanted the contents of a directory (aka "folder") then you've gotten your answer. If you wnat to "view" the files" then you need to clarify and I would start by giving the question a different title.